# Range over `type x []struct` or `type y struct`?

Tags: go

It seems that there is no `Ranger` interface for ranging over custom types. Is there anything similar? Or do I have to make a method that converts the type to a slice or map?

Edit: of course I could cast x to []struct, but that would make it harder to change the underlying type of x.

Comment: Could you post an example of this issue? I'm having a hard time visualizing what you are asking.

Comment: The range clause of the `for` statement works for custom types too. Check out [this example on Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/HSDGKWYhLq).

Comment: @icza Only if your “custom” type is a renamed primitive type you can `range` over.

Comment: @FUZxxl Is `type x []struct {a, b int}` a renamed primitive type? Because the example I linked uses this and it works.

Comment: @icza Yes. “primitive” was the wrong word; I should have said “a renamed type you can range over.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `range` variant of the `for` loop is not extendable to custom collections that are not just renamed slices, maps, strings, or channels. There is no `Ranger` interface or anything like that. If you want to range over a custom type, consider using a `for`-loop like this:

```
for x, eof := col.Next(); x, eof = col.Next(); !eof {
    // ...
}
```

where `Next()` is a method that iterates through your collection with a signature like this:

```
func (*MyCollection) Next() (ItemType x, bool eof)
```